# What changes will result in a changed etag Youtube API V3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the /playlists and /playlistItems endpoints. Right now I am storing the etag for the playlists resource, but I'm not sure whether that etag will change if videos are added to the playlist. Do I also need to save etags from the playlistItems request?

If so, I noticed that each page of 50 videos in playlistItems has its own etag. If a video is added to end of the playlist, will the first page sent have a changed etag? I couldn't find where YouTube documents etag behaviour like this in their docs.

Comment: Don't know if it answers your question but [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags) is the documentation.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison that is just the general usage of etags, but i want to know within each particular resource what triggers its etag to change

Comment: i'm looking for the same thing... i can't seem to find a list of examples of what event/modification will change the ETag of a particular resource (channel list/playlist/etc)... for example... does uploading a video to a playlist change the channel ETag? (obviously it would change the playlist ETag... but what about the channel ETag?)